# Parsing for escape characters with a regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, csv

I'm creating a comma-separated script to store various pieces of data for a project.

The last part of my data line is always a summary of the preceding data (it is always a string of any character except newline characters). The problem is that I split the entire line along the commas, so if this summary portion of the line has commas in it, anything after the excess commas will be split as well, which I don't want.

So I'd like to make my own escape character for commas. I figure that the least error-prone way to do this is with regular expressions.

I've come up with the following expression, `^,(?!\\,)$` which I had hoped would look for commas, but not escaped commas. Unfortunately, it did not work.

The following two lines illustrate how my data is separated.

```
01, 0, 80.0, 0x00100204, 0x00000000, 0x00000800, 0xFFFFF800, 0.02, 0.5, Channel 01: Voltage Offset\,\,\,comma 
02, 0, 80.0, 0x00100208, 0x00000000, 0x00000800, 0xFFFFF800, 0.02, 0.5, Channel 02: Voltage Offset
```

Note that in the first line of data, I have excess commas in there, denoted by `\,\,\,comma`

But when I call `Regex.Split(line, @"^,(?!\,)$");`, nothing happens, I just get a single element array containing my entire string.

Comment: why don't you use a csv parser library instead ?

Comment: FYI `^$` are [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) matching the beginning and end of the string

Comment: @Selman22 My script isn't a pure CSV file; it's got a number of keywords and whatnot to help separate sections of data

Comment: Since the structure is the same up until the last part I would explore using capture groups to capture into two groups. You then do what you need to do with each part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example to use negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\\),
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/gG3cX2/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regex, instead of splitting the string I'd suggest to capture the fields by matching the following regex:

```
\s*((?:\\.|[^\\])+?)\s*(?:,\s*|$)
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/lP8yE1/4

Each match will be a field, and the value will be the contents of capture group 1.

Comment: Well I have to eventually split the data so that I can parse out the string and turn them into numeric variables which I can do math on in my code. So I'm not sure if I can do this using capture fields

Comment: @audiFanatic Call `Regex.Matches` on the whole line, you will get one `Match` object per field. For each match, use `match.Groups[1].Value`. This will contain the field value (without the comma nor surrounding whitespace) which you can directly use in your code (these are the values highlighted in green on the regex101 demo page).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern that checks if there is not a backslash before:

```
Regex.Split(line, @"(?<!\\), ");
```

`(?<!...)` is a lookbehind assertion and means: *not preceded by*

Comment: It'd be better if you checked there is an odd number of backslashes before the comma.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Since the text field is the only possible field that can contain backslahes, it is not needed.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte This doesn't work in all cases. Commas seem to escape themselves. It's not the worst thing in the world because the summary is at the end of the line, but should I choose to rearrange things later, it might be troublesome. For example, `01, 0, 80.0, 0x00100204, 0x00000000, 0x00000800, 0xFFFFF800, 0.02, 0.5, Channel 01: Voltage Offset\, hello\, 222,,,comma`

Comment: @audiFanatic: In this case, forget to search the escaped (or not) commas, and use a limited simple split with ','.(since you seem to have always the same number of fields).