# How to scan for a string literal allowing escaped characters?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, escaping

I would like to parse an input string and determine if it contains a sequence of characters surrounded by double quotes (`"`).
The sequence of characters itself is not allowed to contain further double quotes, unless they are escaped by a backslash, like so: `\"`.

To make things more complicated, the backslashes can be escaped themselves, like so: `\\`. A double quote preceded by two (or any even number of) backslashes (`\\"`) is therefore not escaped.
And to make it even worse, single non-escaping backslashes (i.e. followed by neither `"` nor `\`) are allowed.

I'm trying to solve that with Python's `re` module.
The [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) tells us about the pipe operator `A|B`:

> As the target string is scanned, REs separated by `'|'` are tried from left to right. When one pattern completely matches, that branch is accepted. This means that once `A` matches, `B` will not be tested further, even if it would produce a longer overall match. In other words, the `'|'` operator is never greedy.

However, this doesn't work as I expected:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'"(\\[\\"]|[^"])*"', r'"a\"')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='"a\\"'>
```

The idea of this regex is to first check for an escaped character (`\\` or `\"`) and only if that's not found, check for any character that's not `"` (but it could be a single `\`).
This can occur an arbitrary number of times and it has to be surrounded by literal `"` characters.

I would expect the string `"a\"` not to match at all, but apparently it does.
I would expect `\"` to match the `A` part and the `B` part not to be tested, but apparently it is.

I don't really know how the backtracking works in this very case, but is there a way to avoid it?

I guess it would work if I check first for the initial `"` character (and remove it from the input) in a separate step.
I could then use the following regular expression to get the content of the string:

```
>>> re.match(r'(\\[\\"]|[^"])*', r'a\"')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='a\\"'>
```

This would include the escaped quote. Since there wouldn't be a closing quote left, I would know that overall, the given string does not match.

Do I have to do it like that or is it possible to solve this with a single regular expression and no additional manual checking?

In my real application, the `"`-enclosed string is only one part of a larger pattern, so I think it would be simpler to do it all at once in a single regular expression.

I found similar questions, but those don't consider that a single non-escaping backslash can be part of the string: [regex to parse string with escaped characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10208694/500098), [Parsing for escape characters with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25163186/500098).

Comment: See this: `"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"` --> `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`

Comment: Thanks, that works great! What do you mean by the arrow? Is one of the alternatives better than the other? Are they exactly equivalent?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. All right, let me put that as an answer, since that works for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `"(\\[\\"]|[^"])*"`, you match `"` followed by 0+ sequences of `\` followed by either `\` or `"`, or non-`"`, and then followed by a "closing" `"`. Note that when your input is `"a\"`, the `\` is matched by the second alternative branch `[^"]` (as the backslash is a valid non-`"`).

You need to exclude the `\` from the non-`"`:

```
"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"
      ^^
```

So, we match `"`, then either non-`"` and non-`\` (with `[^\\"]`) or any escape sequence (with `\\.`), 0 or more times.

However, this regex is not efficient enough as there is much backtracking going on (caused by the alternation and the quantifier). Unrolled version is:

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI2gK8/2)

The last pattern matches:

- `"` - a double quote
- `[^"\\]*` - zero or more characters other than `\` and `"`
- `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\\.` - a backslash followed with any character but a newline
  - `[^"\\]*` - zero or more characters other than `\` and `"`
- `"` - a double quote

Comment: That's definitely the way to go, but I'm still wondering why my original expression matches ``\`` instead of `\"`, where latter is `A` (on the left side of `|`). The docs say "once `A` matches, `B` will not be tested further". How comes that `B` matches in this case?

Comment: The answer is: backtracking makes it possible for the `[^"]` to match ``\``, not ``\"``. Your `\\["\\]` is the first and after `"a` are matched with 2 passes of `[^"]` the ``\"`` are grabbed by the first alternative. BUT, the last `"` is *obligatory*, it means the regex engine will try to re-group the captured values it found so far to accommodate some place for the `"`. The engine backtracks, and finds a ``\`` before `"` that can be matched with the second alternative branch `[^"]`. See [your regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/dZ4bB2/2), Steps 12, 13 on the *regex debugger* page.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I think I understand! I'm new to this whole regex thing and I didn't know the *regex debugger*, which is a really great tool for understanding how those regexes work.

Comment: Great I could help. The backtracking is both good and evil in regex, you will quickly realize it. Unfortunately, `re` Python module does not support possessive quantifiers, nor atomic groups (you can use them with the [PyPi `regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) though), then, you could prevent this, e.g. [`"(\\[\\"]|[^"])*+"`](https://regex101.com/r/dD9xW3/1). Another way is through backreferences/capturing inside a positive lookahead: [`"(?:(?=(\\[\\"]|[^"]))\1)*"`](https://regex101.com/r/dD9xW3/2) (this will work even with Python `re`).